# recordset not showing an error when inserting to locked table

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, recordset

Using Access 2010, WinXP.  I'm trying to update table `test` with

```
Sub testUpdate()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("test")

With rs
 .AddNew
 !field1 = "abc"
 !field2 = "def"
 .Update
End With

End Sub
```

If `test` is locked by another user, the procedure runs, and doesn't update the table (which is fine), but also doesn't produce an error.  If I do the same operation as a SQL insert statement, e.g.

`insert into test (field1,field2) values ("abc","def")`

then I get an error message telling me the insert failed due to lock violations.  How can I make `recordset.update` generate a similar error that I can then handle?  There doesn't seem to be any equivalent for `dbFailOnError` with Recordset, as far as I can tell.

Comment: How is test locked? For example, has the user got the table in design view, opened exclusive, or just a record lock?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at setting the recordset type and lock type if you want to trigger the error's e.g:

```
Currentdb.OpenRecordset("test", dbOpenDynaset, dbPessimistic,)
```

You can test out different variations of these until you find the one that works, the access built in help will list all the available options.